# Finding positions to "print" in large arrays for Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am learning how to get data from arrays and I am slightly stuck on an easy way of locating where that data is to pull it from the array. It feels like there should be an easier way than counting on the screen.

Here is what I have:

```
r2 = requests.get(
    f'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/{apiKey}/lookupevent.php?id={id}')

arr_events = np.array([r2.json()])

#print(arr_events)

event_id = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['idEvent']
locate = arr_events.index('strHomeTeam')
print(locate)
```

The problem is, on the console this prints out a massive array that looks like (I'll give one line, you probably get the idea):

```
[{'events': [{'idEvent': '1032723', 'idSoccerXML': None, 'idAPIfootball': '592172', 'strEvent': 'Aston Villa vs Liverpool', 'strEventAlternate': 'Liverpool @ Aston Villa', 'strFilename': 'English Premier League 2020-10-04 Aston Villa vs Liverpool'...}]}]
```

It's a sizeable array, enough to cause a minor slowdown if I neced to pull some info.

So, idEvent was easy to pull using the method above. And if I wanted some of these others in the top line, proabably not hard to count to 5 or 6. But I know there must be an easier way for Python to just locate the ones I want. For instance, I want the home and away team:

```
'strHomeTeam': 'Aston Villa', 'strAwayTeam': 'Liverpool',
```

So is there an easier way to just pull the 'strHomeTeam' rather than counting all the way to the point in the array?

I realise this is a basic question - and I have searched and searched, but everything seems to be in a single, really small array and they don't seem to explain getting the data from big arrays easily.

The JSON file is here: https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookupevent.php?id=1032723

Thank you for your help on this - I appreciate it.

Comment: What's with the `np.array([...])` call? The NumPy array is giving you no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: I don't see why counting would be involved at all. If you want to retrieve the value of the `'strHomeTeam'` key in a dict, you just do `...['strHomeTeam']`, just like you did `...['idEvent']`.

Comment: I think I worked that out a bit late... haha... thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there an easier way to just pull the 'strHomeTeam' rather than counting all the way to the point in the array?

Try the below

```
data = {"events": [
    {"idEvent": "1032723", "idSoccerXML": "", "idAPIfootball": "592172", "strEvent": "Aston Villa vs Liverpool",
     "strEventAlternate": "Liverpool @ Aston Villa",
     "strFilename": "English Premier League 2020-10-04 Aston Villa vs Liverpool", "strSport": "Soccer",
     "idLeague": "4328", "strLeague": "English Premier League", "strSeason": "2020-2021",
     "strDescriptionEN": "Aston Villa and Liverpool square off at Villa Park, where last season, these teams produced one of the most exciting finishes of the campaign, as Liverpool scored twice late on to overturn an early Trezeguet goal.",
     "strHomeTeam": "Aston Villa", "strAwayTeam": "Liverpool", "intHomeScore": "7", "intRound": "4",
     "intAwayScore": "2", "intSpectators": "", "strOfficial": "", "strHomeGoalDetails": "", "strHomeRedCards": "",
     "strHomeYellowCards": "", "strHomeLineupGoalkeeper": "", "strHomeLineupDefense": "",
     "strHomeLineupMidfield": "", "strHomeLineupForward": "", "strHomeLineupSubstitutes": "",
     "strHomeFormation": "", "strAwayRedCards": "", "strAwayYellowCards": "", "strAwayGoalDetails": "",
     "strAwayLineupGoalkeeper": "", "strAwayLineupDefense": "", "strAwayLineupMidfield": "",
     "strAwayLineupForward": "", "strAwayLineupSubstitutes": "", "strAwayFormation": "", "intHomeShots": "",
     "intAwayShots": "", "strTimestamp": "2020-10-04T18:15:00+00:00", "dateEvent": "2020-10-04",
     "dateEventLocal": "2020-10-04", "strDate": "", "strTime": "18:15:00", "strTimeLocal": "19:15:00",
     "strTVStation": "", "idHomeTeam": "133601", "idAwayTeam": "133602", "strResult": "", "strVenue": "Villa Park",
     "strCountry": "England", "strCity": "", "strPoster": "", "strFanart": "",
     "strThumb": "https:\/\/www.thesportsdb.com\/images\/media\/event\/thumb\/r00vzl1601721606.jpg", "strBanner": "",
     "strMap": "", "strTweet1": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/brfootball\/status\/1312843172385521665",
     "strTweet2": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/TomJordan21\/status\/1312854281444306946",
     "strTweet3": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/FutbolBible\/status\/1312847622592442370",
     "strVideo": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=0Nbw3jSafGM", "strStatus": "Match Finished", "strPostponed": "no",
     "strLocked": "unlocked"}]}
filtered_data = [{'home':entry['strHomeTeam'],'away':entry['strAwayTeam']}for entry in data['events']]
print(filtered_data)
```

output

```
[{'home': 'Aston Villa', 'away': 'Liverpool'}]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will definitely use this method. It really is tough when there's something quite simple but the answer just isn't as easy to find as hoped :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Ug... I tried something different and it worked - sigh... I am sorry.

```
event_id = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['idEvent']
home_team = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['strHomeTeam']
away_team = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['strAwayTeam']
home_score = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['intHomeScore']
away_score = arr_events[0]['events'][0]['intAwayScore']
```

I assume this is the right way to do it.

Comment: see my answer. It is a generic one.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into
https://python-json-pointer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

inspect the json, get the path you want to access the value -> use https://github.com/stefankoegl/python-json-pointer